# TypeScript: Conditional Return Type based on Parameter

Tags: typescript, strictnullchecks

I'm working on a TypeScript service where a function returns a `User | null`. I want to modify the return type to be `User` when the `throwIfNotFound` parameter is set to true. This ensures an exception is thrown if the user isn't found, avoiding redundant null checks with TypeScript's `strictNullChecks` enabled.

Reproducible example:

```js
interface IOptions {
    throwIfNotFound?: boolean;
}

interface User {
    id: number;
}

const userArray: User[] = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }];

function findUserById(id: number, options: IOptions): User | undefined {
    const { throwIfNotFound = false } = options;

    let user: User | undefined;

    if (id !== null) {
        user = userArray.find((u) => u.id === id);
    }

    if (throwIfNotFound && !user) {
        throw new Error("User not found");
    }

    return user;
}

const user1 = findUserById(1, { throwIfNotFound: true }); //User exists so no error is thrown and user1 isn't undefined
console.log(user1.id); // 'user1' is possibly 'undefined'.ts(18048)
```

Is there a way to do this using TypeScript?

Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] this code to be a [mre] that we can copy and paste into our own IDEs and get to work on it. That means it should be self-contained and not just be an excerpt of some larger code base whose types and imports we need in order to look at it.  Right now if I look at this in my IDE I get a bunch of errors, none of which you're asking about, so it's hard to get started.

Comment: Sorry @jcalz, I've changed the code to a minimal reproducible example

Comment: For this to work you need your function to either be generic or overloaded, which will let callers see the behavior your want. Either way the function implementation cannot  be properly verified as type safe by the compiler, so you'll need to be careful to make sure the implementation is correct yourself. [This playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mZ5d9N) shows an approach using generics and conditional types. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks @jcalz, it worked, but I don't fully understand what you did. I appreciated that if you can write an answer explaining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the output of `findUserById()` to either be `User` or `User | undefined` depending on the inputs.  But the only way for function output types to depend on input types is if you either [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) the function (giving it multiple call signatures) or make it [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).  Neither method can be verified as type safe by the compiler in the implementation (it's beyond the compiler's abilities) so each approach is mostly useful from the caller's perspective.

---

Traditionally you would overload it, like this:

```
// call signatures
function findUserById(id: number, options: IOptions & { throwIfNotFound: true }): User;
function findUserById(id: number, options: IOptions): User | undefined;

// implementation
function findUserById(id: number, options: IOptions) {
  const { throwIfNotFound = false } = options;
  let user: User | undefined;
  if (id !== null) {
    user = userArray.find((u) => u.id === id);
  }
  if (throwIfNotFound && !user) {
    throw new Error("User not found");
  }
  return user
}
```

The function body is only loosely checked by the compiler.  If you changed the check `(throwIfNotFound && !user)` to `(!throwIfNotFound && !user)` the compiler wouldn't be able to tell anything was wrong. So be careful.

When you call an overloaded function the compiler resolves the call signature (mostly) by trying each call signature in order until it finds a match, which gives you the behavior you're looking for:

```
const user1 = findUserById(1, { throwIfNotFound: true });
//    ^? const user1: User

const user2 = findUserById(1, {});
//    ^? const user2: User | undefined
```

---

Alternatively, you could make the function generic and give it a [conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) return type that depends on the input type.  This approach can sometimes be preferable to overloads, especially if the input-output relationship is too complicated to be written as some small number of nongeneric call signatures.

The conditional type could look like this:

```
type FindUserById<O extends IOptions> = 
  User | (O["throwIfNotFound"] extends true ? never : undefined)
```

Where `FindUserById<O>` will always contain `User`, but will either contain nothing else ([the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type)) or `undefined` depending on whether the input type `O` [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `IOptions` has a `true` type for `throwIfNotFound` (using [the indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `O["throwIfNotFound"]` to look up that property).

Then the function looks like

```
function findUserById<O extends IOptions>(id: number, options: O): FindUserById<O> {
  const { throwIfNotFound = false } = options;

  let user: User | undefined;

  if (id !== null) {
    user = userArray.find((u) => u.id === id);
  }

  if (throwIfNotFound && !user) {
    throw new Error("User not found");
  }

  return user as FindUserById<O>
}
```

Again the compiler can't check the function body properly. Here if you wrote `return user` the compiler would complain because it can't be sure if `user` is appropriately a `FindUserById<O>`. So we use [a type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) `as FindUserById<O>` to tell the compiler we're sure we know what we're doing.  Again, that's something we need to be careful about; the same issue with `!throwIfNotFound` would happen.

And again, this looks good from the caller's side:

```
const user1 = findUserById(1, { throwIfNotFound: true });
//    ^? const user1: User
console.log(user1.id);
const user2 = findUserById(1, {});
//    ^? const user2: User | undefined
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkgJbAAuEATgGYLICSA8jGcQPbBR6FFJkAWlNgHd61AHJsyAMTYBXYABMA-AC4kAIzZsMEEMADcPAL74epCjTpIAqlCrdeJReuBywGqkaKme8DlBkSHL2lACClJQgAJ7qdlQA2gC6SAC8SAm4zuoAjEjGADR42UgATPlFWcQuSADM+UlGZkSgkLDWjABuVBhsIIrczbzUCvCsHEjUpIrxlABC0fSKABTVru6elEVsLOyc6ky7AUgAZMUCQqISUrIKNWSUcsjGAJRxod7Do+PAk9OzCyWqxqbg8VG2R32SEOPygb1soSQAB9gkoIFNgBBFJ8iCNgGM9n8lADFis1khQZsIbCDsxYS9HE4kP5OEEshcRGJJDJ5Eo0pNMPZ8vydrCcbxdEEQlR3g4UXd0aQseKiMRqEhgUgAISpdJuDAYBkEJm8aWUflmiJRaIAOgxK2WcgZqQAfMEbdU0rrnC8VfkeE41RqOVdubc+SczlqzUaA0yQxSIMIkABRSJsSjLABEswpUkmvMUWd9cZ8paQlAgZDklF+ZrjvicLMCwVCeXS9pJQJylT4gk51x5d3UDye+RLTgA9JOnAA9ZTMgJStuyyhDIjN5dUcod-6hQErHt4V7i6dzheb1vb1fI1GKRWYxRmIaNingaBwRBIADiEExlGIeAAGEOEUYgfkwQYnDIaIYGQaQ9yoA8AB5GCQCAAA8KCULgYT2KA3XSXMUWWRgEizEMuRuQssxSTDsMULhR2QBdMW6c11AVDEsReddJm+QlO33UlUPQrC-0Y6E6Xwl1gXWMEtiQUV8PURh4QQ4lhKWVC3WNJlL3ZftQ2ou5+VoDAhWMEVISgJoTUlK9KBveU0W47E+NVdVNR1PU5ANWMTSIM0LVCK0YjtaZlkdZ03TkD0Bl1dJqgnJlX0DLzKMHcMBkjbUY0ZE0E0xZM0yETMc0RYB82oGiUqcNLeErata0cpAQC4DSZi0xQdIbPjLzNdsiS6pDSWWI9DMuKihyUEdHmeOqkDPXh50XVlHJyVc42bHQIBtXoAHNHTbeLFoG0Id2GrtD0qE842WohVvO68ETlO8HyxF8zGMIA)